# Using apt-get on AWS Workspace?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-workspaces

I am trying out [AWS Workspaces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00GNPHHAC) with the Linux package.  Now I want to install some packages, specifically the Atom Editor.  However, neither `dpkg` and `apt` are installed on the command line nor available via `sudo`.  The tool bar does not seem to include aptitude.  How do you install packages?

Comment: It's not a Debian based distribution, so, no, it doesn't have apt. It most likely has a different package manager. It should be mentioned in a FAQ or other documentation.

Comment: Turns out it has `yum` as indicated below. I still don't see documentation for that.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amazon Workspaces for Linux uses Amazon Linux 2.

Packages are managed via the Extras Library.

```
amazon-linux-extras list

amazon-linux-extras install topic
```

[Extras Library (Amazon Linux 2)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#extras-library)